# Google Contacts API error

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-contacts-api

I'm using the following code to get google contacts name and phone number. Authorization page itself is not coming properly it shows error as "The page you requested is invalid". :( pls help me to solve this...

`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("gdata", "1.x");

  var contactsService;
  function setupContactsService()
  {
  contactsService = new google.gdata.contacts.ContactsService('exampleCo-exampleApp-1.0');
  }
  function logMeIn() {
      var scope = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds';
      var token = google.accounts.user.login(scope);
      }
  function initFunc() {
      setupContactsService();
      logMeIn();
      getMyContacts();
      }
  function checkLoggedIn(){
      scope = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds";
      var token = google.accounts.user.checkLogin(scope);

      if(token != "")
      return true;
      else
      return false;
      }
  function getMyContacts() {
      var contactsFeedUri = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full';

      var query = new google.gdata.contacts.ContactQuery(contactsFeedUri);

      //We load all results by default//
      query.setMaxResults(10);

      contactsService.getContactFeed(query, handleContactsFeed, ContactsServiceInitError);
      }
//Gets the contacts feed passed as parameter//
  var handleContactsFeed = function(result) {

  //All contact entries//
  entries = result.feed.entry;
  for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
      var contactEntry = entries[i];
      var telNumbers = contactEntry.getPhoneNumbers();
      var title = contactEntry.getTitle().getText();
      }
}
</script> 
<body>
<input type="submit" value="Login to Google" id="glogin"  onclick="initFunc();">
</body>`
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to use the Google Contacts 1.X API. That's been deprecated. Look at the [JavaScript examples for the Google 3.X API](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/wiki/Samples) and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this example

```
var config = {
  'client_id': 'Client ID',
  'scope': 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds'
};

inviteContacts = function() {
   gapi.auth.authorize($scope.config, function() {
       fetch(gapi.auth.getToken());
   });
}

function fetch(token) {
    $.get("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?access_token=" + token.access_token + "&alt=json", function(response) {
         console.log(response);
         //console.log(response.data.feed.entry);
    });
}
```

Don't forget to add `<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>` into your html file. Good Luck!